# Can't create my question, because it looks like spam

Tags: support, asking-questions, spam-detection

I have read a lot about this theme now and I don't get why my question looks like a spam...

Question:
[image: Question]

[image: Question]

Comment: This probably isn't it, but maybe try replacing the `XXX`s with some other placeholder? I can't think of anything else that would look like spam, since there's not even any links or email addresses (though I don't know much about how the spam detection works).

Comment: Unrelated - please [omit salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), such as that "Hey", from posts

Comment: Try removing the pseudo-email "info@domain".

Answer (score 5):

The solution was to delete the "Hey".

Edit: This wasn't the solution. I have tried before to post and it says revisions look good I'm ready to post but I have to wait 90 min because of this question. "You can only create a question every 90 min."

Now I was trying again and get the same error. "Looks like spam".

Comment: Can I delete this answer?

Comment: Try replacing the XXX, as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I have didn't work

Comment: For some reason I could create the same question now :)